# How to add vertex groups from one object to another without replacing them?

Tags: blender

I am using blender to create a human model and i have two models one is rigged with a list of vertex groups and another copy of the same model has another set of vertex groups. I was wondering if there is anyway i can have a copy of the same model with both these sets of vertex groups. Or a way i can copy the vertex groups from one model to another without replacing the already existing vertex groups.

Comment: Does [this help](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16273/935)?

Comment: This replaces the vertex group in one with the ones in the other object...I want to append or add to the existing vertex groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an addon included with blender that can copy vertex weights from the active object to the other selected objects. As you mention the addon will overwrite any existing vertex weights that have matching names.

By taking the code that does the vertex weight copy from the addon and making a small adjustment so that it uses a new name for the destination vertex group when the name already exists, I get the following small script.

Paste it into blender's [text editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/text_editor.html) and click run script. The vertex groups in the [active object](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/selecting.html) are copied to any other selected objects.

```
import bpy

active = bpy.context.active_object

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    me_source = active.data
    me_target = ob.data

    # sanity check: do source and target have the same amount of verts?
    if len(me_source.vertices) != len(me_target.vertices):
        print('ERROR: objects {} and {} have different vertex counts.'.format(active.name,ob.name))
        continue

    vgroups_IndexName = {}
    for i in range(0, len(active.vertex_groups)):
        groups = active.vertex_groups[i]
        vgroups_IndexName[groups.index] = groups.name
    data = {}  # vert_indices, [(vgroup_index, weights)]
    for v in me_source.vertices:
        vg = v.groups
        vi = v.index
        if len(vg) > 0:
            vgroup_collect = []
            for i in range(0, len(vg)):
                vgroup_collect.append((vg[i].group, vg[i].weight))
            data[vi] = vgroup_collect
    # write data to target
    if ob != active:
        # add missing vertex groups
        for vgroup_idx, vgroup_name in vgroups_IndexName.items():
            #check if group already exists...
            already_present = 0
            for i in range(0, len(ob.vertex_groups)):
                if ob.vertex_groups[i].name == vgroup_name:
                    vgroup_name = vgroup_name+'_from_'+active.name
                    vgroups_IndexName[vgroup_idx] = vgroup_name
            # ... if not, then add
            if already_present == 0:
                ob.vertex_groups.new(name=vgroup_name)
        # write weights
        for v in me_target.vertices:
            for vi_source, vgroupIndex_weight in data.items():
                if v.index == vi_source:

                    for i in range(0, len(vgroupIndex_weight)):
                        groupName = vgroups_IndexName[vgroupIndex_weight[i][0]]
                        groups = ob.vertex_groups
                        for vgs in range(0, len(groups)):
                            if groups[vgs].name == groupName:
                                groups[vgs].add((v.index,),
                                   vgroupIndex_weight[i][1], "REPLACE")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D